# Need some help improving my regex

Tags: regex

```
^(\w+) - (\d+). (.+) \((\d+)\) \[(\w+)]
```

I created the following regex to match a pattern of directories I use to store my music collection in.

The general pattern for the directory structure is like this

```
artist - albumnr. albumname (year) [quality]
```

I am trying to match into groups the artist, albumname, year and quality. However, I would like to clean up the albumname and remove anything that be inside parentheses or any string that would appear after a dash.

e.g.

- `albumname -blahblah (remastered)` - would just return albumname in the 3rd group match
- `albumname (remastered)` - would still just return albumname
- `albumname` - the regex should still be able to return album name even if there is no - or backets within the result.

Comment: What OS and/or command-line interface are you using?

Comment: Also, a few example directory titles would be helpful, rather than just the pattern they take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one will match `albumname -blahblah (remastered)` and `albumname (remastered)` but not `albumname (remastered) -blahblah` :

```
^(\w+) - (\d+)\. (.+?) ?(?:-\w+)? ?(?:\(.*?\))? \((\d+)\) \[(\w+)\]
```

Test [here](http://rubular.com/r/PiHD22n6lt)

If you also want to match against `albumname (remastered) -blahblah`

```
^(\w+) - (\d+)\. (.+?) ?(?:-\w+)? ?(?:\(.*?\))? ?(?:-\w+)? \((\d+)\) \[(\w+)\]
```

Comment: Thanks that worked just perfectly! The regex is helpful in helping me collect artwork for my albums by removing erroneous titles with brackets in the album name or words like (reissue), (remastered) etc which always appear in brackets. It's great not having to make a list of keywords to remove and the regex helps tidy up the album title for a more accurate artwork search.